# Counting data categories on excel

Tags: excel

For the last part of my genome analysis I have to make a pie chart related to gene function. I have an excel spreadsheet with the gene function and the corresponding letter category (COG letter column D in screenshot), to make the pie chart I need to filter by column C so I can adjust the number of genomes depending on which ones I am looking at in certain parts of the analysis and then count how many times this letter appears in the list of ~4000 genes. After filtering by Column C, I would like to make a table that looks like the second screenshot. The issue is some letters appear more than once e.g. EGP (row 40 - would need to be counted as one E and one G and one P separately in the table for the pie chart). Any advice/formulas greatly appreciated.
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can use COUNTIF with wildcards `*`.

Comment: I apologise, I'm new to big datasets on excel, what are wildcards?

Comment: For example, `=COUNTIF(D:D,"*E*")` will count both a standalone `E` and the E in `EGP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COUNTIF` with wildcards.  For example:

```
=COUNTIF(D:D,"*E*")
```

will count both a standalone "E" as well as the E in "EGP".